# Centering a Page issue

Tags: html, css, center

Ok, lets see if i can explain this. My page content has a width of 960px. It is centered in another div that has a width of 1426px (#siteWrap).

```
#siteWrap{
margin:0px auto;
width:1426px;
background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat ;
}
```

What i need to find out is how to get #siteWrap to center on a page regardless of screen resolutions. Most of my visitors are on a 1024x768 screen resolution. When i test this page on that resolution i am forced to scroll left to right to get to the site content.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is in #siteWrap? Is it just a background image? Why does it need to be 1426px wide?

Comment: Yeah its just a background image. The reason i didn't add this image to be body is because the body is already using an image that repeats itself. 

So I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 2):

Just set

width: 100%;

and the margin: 0 auto; should be set on your content div, not on this one.

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what the OP is asking for.  This would cause the background to position top-left, rather than being centered on the page, which would mean the content would not be positioned on the center of the background.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. The div would be 100%, with the content div of 960px being inside of it, centered with margin: 0 auto;. How did reach that conclusion?

Comment: Sorry, I guess that wasn't completely clear.  Your solution would work, as long as you added background-position:center;  Otherwise, by default the background image would be positioned in the top-left of your 100% width div.  Without that, the content would be positioned in the center of the page, but the background would be top-left, so they wouldn't align properly in the middle.

Comment: (I just assumed that background-position:center was obvious. I shouldn't assume :)

Answer (score 0):

When a container overflows horizontally, the browsers natural reaction is to dock it to the left side of the screen.  I think it *should* be doing this.  To get around it, you can [use Javascript to center your container element](http://blog.josh420.com/archives/2007/10/centering-an-element-on-the-page-with-javascript-cross-browser.aspx) by calculating the necessary offsets based on screen/viewport resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#sitewrap {
   position:absolute;
   top:0px;
   left:50%;
   width:1426px;
   margin-left:-713px;
   background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat ;
}
```

This will be centered but will overflow the browser window.